# Which IDE and toolchain on Windows to generate a program for an embedded arm linux?

Tags: linux, windows, arm, cross-platform

I usually work on linux when i have a linux target but this time i must work from a Windows based computer and must keep all my work on Windows.

I tried with Code::blocks and GNUARM, the build has no problem but can't be runned on the target.

When using code sourcery G++ i can build with command a single .c file and it runs on my board.

When i try to put the sourcery g++ exécutables in a toolchain configuration in code::blocks the software seems to build with no error but is generating nothing...

Now i would like to go a step further an build a project, no more single files, and i don't seems to be able to find a solution to this problem.

Does anyone here has experience from this kind of situation ?

Comment: Android NDK, maybe? It's close enough to Linux, it generates ARM/ELF files... Or consider an ARM virtual machine with Linux and a native toolchain.

Comment: I finally got it to work, here is a little explanation on how i did it : first i installed the jdk and eclipse, the code sourcery g++ lite and finally the gnu arm Tools (not the gnu arm plugin). I then went into the toolchain configuration in eclipse and changed the Tools "cs-make" and "cs-rm" from code sourcery to the "make" and "rm" from the gnu arm Tools kit. I changed the format from c++11 to c++9 too and now i am generated a elf file which run on my board.

Comment: Write an answer and accept it. That's how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work, here is a little explanation on how i did it : first i installed the jdk and eclipse, the code sourcery g++ lite and finally the gnu arm Tools (not the gnu arm plugin). I then went into the toolchain configuration in eclipse and changed the Tools "cs-make" and "cs-rm" from code sourcery to the "make" and "rm" from the gnu arm Tools kit. I changed the format from c++11 to c++9 too and now i am generated a elf file which run on my board.